# serving multiple networks with one single DHCPv6 server

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, ipv6, dhcp-server

I have an ISC DHCPv6 server running on a debian (Stretch) machine and 3 physical networks : net1, net2 & net3 . The router is a Debian machine running the Zebra routing software (See picture below).

I installed a relay agent (dhcp-helpler) on the router to transform DHCPv6 broadcast packets to unicast packets that are directly sent to the DHCPv6 server.

My current problem is : isc-dhcp-server must have an interface within the subnet it is supposed to serve. But i my case It is not. How should i configure the isc-dhcp-server in this case to serve the different physical networks that are not in the same domain with the dhcp server ?

dhcpd6 conf file : (Until this moment, i only configured to serve the net1 machines)

```
# /etc/dhcp/dhcpd6.conf

default-lease-time 2592000;
preferred-lifetime 604800;
option dhcp-renewal-time 3600;
option dhcp-rebinding-time 7200;
allow leasequery;
option dhcp6.info-refresh-time 21600;

subnet6 2001:192:168:1::/64 {

    range6 2001:192:168:1::128 2001:192:168:1::256;
}
```

network interface configuration :

```
# ip addr show enp0s8
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
        inet6 2001:10::2/64 scope global 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe75:98f6/64 scope link 
           valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The error message from the isc-dhcp-server :

```
No subnet6 declaration for enp0s8 (2001:10::2).
** Ignoring requests on enp0s8.  If this is not what
   you want, please write a subnet6 declaration
   in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
   to which interface enp0s8 is attached. **
```

Network topology : 
[image]

Comment: So... What happens if you add the `subnet6` blocks for those other networks?

Comment: @grawity It's the same problem. I think there should be some kind of a special packet forwarding for DHCP. I don't really know.